# Why does score evaluate score +1 when str is set to opt2

Tags: javascript

I have a function which calculates the score in a survey depending on the chosen option, but I am always getting the same value which is in the first if condition

```
var questions = [{
        "question": "L'impact est ",
        option1: "faible",
        option2: "moyen",
        option3: "haut",
    },   

var currentQuestion = 0;
var score1 = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;
var number = 0;


var progressText = document.getElementById("progressText");
var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');



function loadQuestion(questionIndex) {
    var q = questions[questionIndex];
    questionEl.textContent = (questionIndex + 1) + '. ' + q.question;
    opt1.textContent = q.option1;
    opt2.textContent = q.option2;
    opt3.textContent = q.option3;
    progressText.innerText = questionIndex + 1 + ' de ' + totQuestions + ' 
questions ';
 };

  function loadNextQuestion() {
    var selectedOption = 
document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
    if (!selectedOption) {
        alert('veuillez sélectionner votre réponse');
        return;
    }

        var answer =selectedOption.Value;
    
        if (questions[currentQuestion].opt1 == answer) {
            score1 += 1;
        } else if (questions[currentQuestion].opt2 == answer) {
            score1 += 2;
        } else {
             score1 += 3
    }


    selectedOption.checked = false;
    currentQuestion++;
    progressText.textContent = questionEl / totQuestions

    if (currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1) {
        nextButton.textContent = 'Finish';
    }
    if (currentQuestion == totQuestions) {
        container.style.display = 'none';
        resultCont.style.display = '';
        resultCont.textContent = 'le résultat est ' + ' ' + score1 + ' ' 
+answer+' '+ option1 ;
        return;
    }
    loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
};
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

Comment: And what are the contents of `questions`? (And what is the value of `answer`, while we're at it?)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows the whole problem, there's no way to tell from this what's going wrong.

Comment: See what's the result of `console.log(answer)` and if it's `<select>` element you can get the value using `var ans = document.getElementById("answer"); var answer = ans.options[ans.selectedIndex].value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you well, your problem may be because of one more reason bellow:

1. You don't trigger change event on your `<select>` element.
2. The `answer`'s value, you may need to use `.selectedIndex` to get the answered value.

Have a look at
[onchange Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) , [.selectedIndex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)

```js
var questions = [{
  opt1: "Answer 1",
  opt2: "Answer 2",
  opt3: "Answer 3"
}];

// score1, currentQuestion variables defined as example
var currentQuestion = 0;
var score1 = 1;

var sel = document.getElementById("sel");

sel.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var answer = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  if (questions[currentQuestion].opt1 == answer) {
    score1 += 1;
  } else if (questions[currentQuestion].opt2 == answer) {
    score1 += 2;
  } else {
    score1 += 3;
  }
  console.log("score1 = " + score1)
});
```

```html
<div id="q"></div>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="Answer 1">Answer 1</option>
  <option value="Answer 2">Answer 2</option>
  <option value="Answer 3">Answer 3</option>
</select>
```